# Pseudo-Hamiltonian of atom

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, tight-binding

Consider the pseudo-Hamiltonian of atom i,
[image]

It is said that "the more the states
are localized on the atom and the less they overlap with the neighbouring orbitals, the
more this formalism is transferable, since it is less dependent on the environment. There would be a large degree of cancellation between the third and the fourth terms
on the right-hand side of the equation above."

Can I know why the highly localised states on atom implies large degree of cancellation between third and fourth terms? It seems like it implies the  |jβ> ≈ |iα>  for high localised states on atom, why is it so?

Appreciate your help and detail explanation.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit? where are the equation and the quoted text taken from? what do the different labels $|i,\alpha\rangle$ signify? what are $V_j$? (are they independent of $i$?)

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for displaying mathematics on this site.  It is the site standard and we **very** strongly discourage using images of math (or text).